# How to know if a Constraint is actually with CHECK in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have to check a Constraint in case it was created with NOCHECK; the thing is that some of the constrained data has been fixed and checked after, so I need to check each constraint only if the check is still disabled. For example I have this code;

CODE1 (OK):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MYFK] FOREIGN KEY([TABLE1_id], [TABLE1_Codigo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TABLE2] ([TABLE2_id], [TABLE2_Codigo])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MYFK]
GO
```

Here the Check was added after;

CODE 2 (With the NOCHECK Bug i need to fix):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MYFK] FOREIGN KEY([TABLE1_id], [TABLE1_Codigo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TABLE2] ([TABLE2_id], [TABLE2_Codigo])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MYFK]
GO
```

So I need to know if the constraint has the CHECK

I Have Tried this but as it was created with the NOCHECK it always returns that my contraint is not trusted.

```
SELECT name, tbl = object_name(parent_obj)
FROM sysobjects
WHERE objectproperty(id, 'CnstIsNotTrusted') = 1
```

Is there a way (that does not include to drop and create the constraint again) to know if a constraint is actually with CHECK despite that it was created with NOCHECK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE ... CHECK CONSTRAINT ...` doesn't validate existing data - so it *is* still not trusted.

You need to do `ALTER TABLE ... WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ...` (yes, `CHECK` twice) so that it both validates existing data *and* enforces it for new insertions

See [`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190273.aspx):

> The query optimizer does not consider constraints that are defined `WITH NOCHECK`. Such constraints are ignored until they are re-enabled by using `ALTER TABLE table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL`.

Answer (score 2):

This should return all check constraints that are not trusted.

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(s.NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(i.parent_object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(i.NAME) AS [Constraint]
FROM sys.check_constraints i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.parent_object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE i.is_not_trusted = 1
```

If you want to make the constraints trusted again you can do that using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MYFK]
```

The same can be done with foreign keys. Replace `sys.check_constraints` with `sys.foreign_keys`.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answered the OP's question asking if the check constraint is "checked", i.e., trusted

Answer (score 1):

Just query [sys.check_constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187388.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.check_constraints
WHERE is_disabled = 0;
```

Similiar [sys.foreign_keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189807.aspx)

> is_disabled   bit    CHECK constraint is disabled.
>
> is_not_trusted bit CHECK constraint has not been verified by the system for all rows.

To check if there are data that violate constraints use:

`DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS WITH ALL_CONSTRAINTS`

You have to tell SQL Server to not just enable the constraint, but to recheck all of the data that’s been loaded.

`ALTER TABLE MyTableName WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT MyConstraintName;`

**Warning: For large tables you may need outage window**